# Django don't create the user given image on MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: python, django

It works if i add a new image from the Django admin, but it is not working by my way.

**models.py**

```
 class ModelX(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Picture'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import ModelX

# Create your views here.

def photo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        model = ModelX(
            photo=request.POST['photo']
        )
        model.save()
        return redirect('show')
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def showphoto(request):
    model = ModelX.objects.last()
    return render(request, 'photo.html', {'photo' : model})
```

Comment: A `FileField` or `ImageField` will be in `request.FILES` not `request.POST`. "it is not working" is not enough information for anyone to help you, you need to add a traceback and the exact line(s) that aren't working

Comment: request.FILES is empty, bro, i want to add the user given image to MEDIA_ROOT, if i add the picture through django admin, the image is created in MEDIA_ROOT, the problem is, when i want to do it but through my view, the image isn´t created in MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: Do you have a `Form`? What is triggering the POST request to your view?

Comment: i don't use a form. Here is a repo with the complete code: https://github.com/gianlop3z/error.git

Comment: There is a `<form>` somewhere in a template/HTML that is being used to submit the POST request with the image to your view? Can you share this? You probably haven't set the correct `enctype`

Comment: brooo thanks, that was the problem. my <form> hadn't an enc-tpe="multipart-form-data" defined, so form data was plain text. Man, i've struggling with this error 3 days ago. THANKS!